# Laravel get items based on a many to many relation

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

How do I query in Laravel Eloquent the following criteria

having project, employees tables and a many to many binder project_member table, I want to get projects where a project is owned by logged in user as a team member.

in my Project model I have

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function members()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'project_team', 'id', 'project');
}
```

and user table

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function team()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project', 'project_team', 'employee', 'project');
}
```

and I want to get all projects where logged in user is a member of a given project

Comment: You have `Auth::user()` and want its projects?

Comment: You can simply call that `team` relation from the logged in user object (`Auth::user()`)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I want projects where `Auth::user()` has a reference in project_team table

Comment: So just `Auth::user()->team;`?

Comment: Yes like that works, but I wanted to make that query over my project model and get projects from a logged in user